# Integrate Specs2 results with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sbt, specs2

I want to integrate the Specs2 test results with Jenkins.

I was added the below properties in sbt:

**resolver:**

```
"maven specs2"      at  "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact"
```

**libraryDependencies:**

```
"org.specs2"              %% "specs2"            % "2.0-RC1"                  % "test",
```

**System Property:**

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup(() => System.setProperty("specs2.outDir", "/target/specs2-reports"))              //Option1

//testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup(() => System.setProperty("specs2.junit.outDir", "/target/specs2-reports"))    //Option2

testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "console", "junitxml")
```

If I run the below command, it is not generating any specs reports in the above mentioned directory("/target/specs2-reports").

**sbt> test**

If I run the below command, it is asking for the directory as shown in the below error message:

**sbt> test-only -- junitxml**

[error] Could not run test code.model.UserSpec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: junitxml requires directory to be specified, example: junitxml(directory="xxx")

And it is working only if I give the directory as shown below:

**sbt> test-only -- junitxml(directory="\target\specs-reports")**

But sometimes its not generating all the specs report xmls (some times generating only one report, sometimes only two reports etc.).

If I give **test-only -- junitxml(directory="\target\specs-reports")** in the jenkins it is giving the below error.

```
[error] Not a valid key: junitxml (similar: ivy-xml)
[error] junitxml(
[error]         ^
```

My main goal is, I want to generate the consolidated test reports in junit xml format and integrate with Jenkins. Kindly help me to solve my problem.

Best Regards,

Hari

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option for the junitxml output directory is: "specs2.junit.outDir" and the default value is "target/test-reports".

So if you don't change anything you could just instruct Jenkins to grab the xml files from "target/test-reports" which is what I usually do.

Also you might have to enclose your sbt commands in Jenkins with quotes. This is what I typically do:

```
"test-only -- html junitxml console"
```